# Use array of ints parameter in FromSQL query and Where In clause

Tags: entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-core-3.1

I have a list of ints:

var ids = new List { 10, 20 };

And I need to find Users with that ids:

```
context.Users.FromSqlInterpolated($@" 
  select Users.* 
  where Users.Id in ({String.Join(',', ids)})"
```

But I get the following error:

```
'Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '10, 20' to data type int.'
```

How can I use such a parameter?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using `Interpolated` method is not appropriate here, because `{String.Join(',', ids)}` defines single string placeholder, hence EF Core binds single `nvarchar` parameter with value `'10,20'`, so the actual SQL is like this

```sql
select Users.* 
where Users.Id in ('10,20')
```

which is invalid, hence the exception.

You should use `Raw` method instead. Either

```cs
var query = context.Users.FromSqlRaw($@" 
select Users.* 
where Users.Id in ({String.Join(',', ids)})");
```

which will embed literal values

```sql
select Users.* 
where Users.Id in (10,20)
```

or if you want to parameterize it, generate parameter placeholders like `{0}`, `{1}` etc. inside the SQL and pass values separately:

```cs
var placeholders = string.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(0, ids.Count)
    .Select(i => "{" + i + "}"));
var values = ids.Cast<object>().ToArray();

var query = context.Users.FromSqlRaw($@" 
select Users.* 
where Users.Id in ({placeholders})", values);
```

which would generate SQL like this

```sql
select Users.* 
where Users.Id in (@p0,@p1)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is awesome for a SQL Injection hack. Where do you work?

Comment: @kolobcreek the input is just a list of ints. Good luck with your SQL injection.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to combine `.FromSql()` and SQL `WHERE x IN ()` then perform a second operation on the output `IQueryable<T>` of the `.FromSql()` call.

```cs
var ids = new List { 10, 20 };
var query = context.Users.FromSqlInterpolated(
  $@"select *
     from Users");
if (ids?.Count > 0)
{
  query = query.Where(user => ids.Contains(user.Id));
}
```

Resultant SQL approximates to:

```sql
select * from (
  select * 
  from Users
) u
where u.Id in (10,20)
```

- No invalid SQL if ids is empty
- No empty result if ids is empty string (I was working with a string data type)

Answer (score 0):

This solution is for EfCore 6.x.
This is a different parameterized solution uses a Table-Value Parameter and may be more efficient or more practical than using `queryable.Where(q => ids.Contains(q.id))` for some use-cases.

1. Define a type in Database

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Ids] AS TABLE (
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL);
```

2. Create a SqlParameter that maps to the Type from step 1. I wrote an extension method to do this, but the initialization could be locally scoped.

```
public static SqlParameter ToIdsTableValueParameter(this IEnumerable<string> ids)
{
    DataTable dataTable = new();
    dataTable.Columns.Add("Id");
    foreach (string id in ids)
    {
        dataTable.Rows.Add(new string[] { id });
    }

    return new SqlParameter()
    {
        ParameterName = "ids",
        TypeName = "[dbo].[Ids]",
        SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured,
        Value = dataTable
    };
}
```

3. Chain the `dbset.fromSqlInterpolated(...)` where the @param is is the SqlParameter from step 2.

```
await dbContext.YourEntities
    .FromSqlInterpolated(
        $"select * from yourEntities y join {@param} ids on ids.id = y.Id")
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken)
```